# How can I find this probability of multiple Random Variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

I am going to calculate this probability
\begin{align}
 P=\Pr\left\{  \frac{1+X_1}{1+Y}> a \cap \frac{1+\frac{X_2}{X_2+1}}{1+\frac{Y}{Y+1}} >b \right\}
\end{align}
I tried to calculate as follows:
\begin{align}
  P&=\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} \Pr\left\{  \frac{1+X_1}{1+y}> a \cap 
 \frac{1+\frac{X_2}{X_2+1}}{1+\frac{y}{y+1}} >b \right\} f_{Y} (y) dy
\\
  &=\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} \Pr\left\{  \frac{1+X_1}{1+y}> a \right\} \Pr
 \left\{ \frac{1+\frac{X_2}{X_2+1}}{1+\frac{y}{y+1}} >b \right\} f_{Y} (y) dy
\end{align}
Here, $X_i$, $Y$ are exponential random variable with mean value $\Omega_{X_i}$ and $\Omega_{Y}$, respectively.
However, when I do Monte Carlo simulation, it does not match well. Do you know what is the reason and is there any way to find this probability?

Thank you!